# GREP: exclude file extensions in specific directory

Tags: bash, grep

My code takes added, modified, deleted, renamed, copied files from `git status -s` and compare them with the list of file paths from the file.

```
git status -s |
grep -E "^M|^D|^A|^R|^C" |
awk '{if ($1~/M+/ || $1~/D+/ || $1~/A+/ || $1~/R+/ || $1~/C+/) print $2}' |
grep --file=$list_of_files --fixed-strings |
grep -r --exclude="*.jar" "SVCS/bus/projects/Resources/"
```

1. Prints out git status like `M foo.txt`
2. Does some "filtering" operations
3. More filtering operations
4. Takes path to files for compare from the text file
5. Here I am trying to make so the last step would exclude `.jar` files from specific directory.

How can I do the last step? Or need to add something to the 4th step?

Comment: Since you have many, many pipes, I do think this can be probably handled in a single process. Please post a sample output of `git status -s` with the final desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the `-r` flag in the last `grep`, but I might be missing something; what about trying `| grep -vE "SVCS/bus/projects/Resources/*.jar"` as last command instead of your current `grep`?

Comment: The part until `awk` could be: `git status -s | awk '$1 ~ /M|D|A|R|C/{print $2}'` .. What is the content of `$list_of_files`?

Comment: Guys, ty, but the answer is bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix is to change the last line to

```
grep -v 'SVCS/bus/projects/Resources/.*\.jar$'
```

but that really is some horrible code you have there.

Keeping in mind that `grep | awk` and `awk | grep` is an [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html), how about this refactoring?

```
git status -s |
grep -E "^M|^D|^A|^R|^C" |
awk '{if ($1~/M+/ || $1~/D+/ || $1~/A+/ || $1~/R+/ || $1~/C+/)
```

... Hang on, what's the point of that?  The `grep` already made sure that `$1` contains one or more of those letters.  The `+` quantifier is completely redundant here.

```
print $2}'
```

Will break on files with whitespace in them.  This is a very common error which is aggravating because a lot of the time, the programmer knew it would break, but just figured "can't happen here".

```
git status -s | awk 'NR==FNR { files[$0] = 1; next }
    /^[MDARC]/ { gsub(/^[MDARC]+ /, ""); 
        if ($0 ~ /SVCS\/bus\/projects\/Resources\/.*\.jar$/)
            next;
        if ($0 in files) print }' "$list_of_files" -
```

The `NR==FNR` thing is a common idiom to read the first file into an array, then fall through to the next input file.  So we read `$list_of_files` into the keys of the associative array `files`; then if the file name we read from `git status` is present in the keys, we print it.  The condition to skip `.jar` files in a particular path is then a simple addition to this Awk script.

This assumes `$list_of_files` really is a list of actual files, as suggested by the file name.  Your code will look for a match anywhere in that file, so a partial file name would also match (for example, if the file contains `path/to/ick`, a file named `somepath/to/icktys/mackerel` would match, and thus be printed).  If that is the intended functionality, the above script will require some rather drastic modifications.

Comment: This code takes output from `git status -s` exmp: `M  Boo.txt` or ` M Far.t` and rips off path to the file or file. After, grep takes it and compares it with the path to files from the file. Now, with exceptions, thanks to you) And thank you for your explanation, I couldn't find one in the internet. And also for that little guide of yours on prettifying my code!